Cloudflare R2 to move data across AWS regions
I saw this tweet from @samgoodwin89 last week:

Cloudflare has no egress fees and AWS has no ingress fees.
Pay egress fees once to move data to R2 and now you can migrate data
to as many AWS regions or cloud providers as you like for $0/GB.

Is this a real option that can be implemented in a serious project?
Or is it just a joke and there are limitation that are not obvious to me and make this approach actually unpractical?
Thanks for your support! and I apologize if this is a dumb question :/

It's not a joke. The pricing for these services is public, you can look it up yourself.

I know the price is correct. What I want to know is whether architecting such a solution is practical or not. It seems to me that there must be some technical difficulties in implementation that I'm not aware of. Otherwise everybody would be doing this

It looks like this can be suitable in some cases, but you need to calculate the costs carefully because storing data in R2 also cost some money.
Regarding transfers, Cloudflare has a special tool called Super Slurper, for data migration from AWS S3 and Google Cloud Storage (GCS), which is currently in beta.
